# Uncaught TypeError: self.video.play is not a function

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, ecmascript-6

Estoy tratando de utilizar la api `getUserMedia` para tomar una foto, he seguido algunos blogs, pero estoy teniendo problemas con el elemento vídeo, al imprimirlo en consola no viene null, pero me marca que `play()` no es una función para video, he intentado [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216804/html5-video-uncaught-typeerror-play-is-not-a-function) , pero no funciono, ¿como podría solucionar esto?

```js
const self = this;

self.videoObj = { "video": true },
  self.errBack = (error) => {
   // alert("Error Capturando el video: ", error.code);
  };

 // Pedir permisos al Navegador para usar la Webcam
 self.camPermission = () => {
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {                    // Standard
   navigator.getUserMedia(self.videoObj, self.iniciarWebcam, self.errBack);
  } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit
   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(self.videoObj, self.iniciarWebcam, self.errBack);
  } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {        // Firefox
   navigator.mozGetUserMedia(self.videoObj, self.iniciarWebcam, self.errBack);
  };
 }


 self.iniciarWebcam = (stream) => {

  self.miCameraOnline = document.getElementById('miCameraOnline');
  //self.video = document.getElementById("video-cam");
  self.video = document.getElementsByClassName('video-cam');
  self.canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas-cam');
  self.video.width = self.video.offsetWidth;
  //self.video.width = 960;

  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {                    // Standard
   self.video.src = stream;
   self.video.play();
  } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {        // WebKit
   self.video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
   self.video.play();
  } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {        // Firefox
   self.video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
   self.video.play();
  };

 };

 // Click para hacer la foto
 self.click = () => {
  // Copiando la imagen a un canvas temporal
  self.temp = document.createElement('canvas');
  console.log(temp)
  self.temp.width = self.video.offsetWidth;
  self.temp.height = self.video.offsetHeight;

  var tempcontext = self.temp.getContext("2d"),
   tempScale = (self.temp.height / self.temp.width);

  self.temp.drawImage(
   self.video,
   0, 0,
   self.video.offsetWidth, self.video.offsetHeight
  );

  // Redimensionar al tamaño de nuestro cavas
  canvas.style.height = parseInt(canvas.offsetWidth * tempScale);
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
   scale = canvas.width / self.temp.width;
  context.scale(scale, scale);
  context.drawImage(bigimage, 0, 0);
 };
```

```html
<div id="miCameraOnline">
  <video class="video-cam"></video>
  <canvas class="video-cam"></canvas>
  <button class="video-cam" onclick="click()">¡Haz Foto!</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu código tienes lo siguiente:

```
self.video = document.getElementsByClassName('video-cam');
self.canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas-cam');
```

Si te fijas, este método indica en su nombre que busca elemento**s**, en plural.
De hecho, devuelve una lista de elementos, por lo que cuando más adelante intentas ejecutar

```
self.video.src = stream;
self.video.play();
```

No puede funcionar porque estás añadiendo una propiedad a la lista y a continuación intentas llamar al método play de la lista... y dicho método no existe.

Si sabes que sólo habrá un elemento video, podrías usar

```
self.video = document.querySelector('.video-cam');
```

que se queda con el primer elemento que cumpla la condición de tener la clase `video-cam`. Otra opción sería poner un ID y usar `getElementById`